# how to read a text file from server and display the text in index.jsp

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am woking on web service.Now I have session folders for each user, and each user has it's log file there. Now I want to read log files from java and pass it to index.jsp for show. As I have already used `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest req` - the `req.setAttribute(REQUEST_IS_LOG, log);` and `req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, res);` do not work for me. Can someone help me to find another way? How can I take the text from file in display it in index? 
Are they any way to do this with ajax?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If it's in public webcontent, just use `<jsp:include>`.

```
<pre>
    <jsp:include page="logs/user123.txt" />
</pre>
```

Otherwise bring a `HttpServlet` in between which gets an `InputStream` of the desired resource and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the response.

```
<pre>
    <jsp:include page="logservlet/user123.txt" />
</pre>
```

Or if it is located at a different public domain, use JSTL `<c:import>`.

```
<pre>
    <c:import url="http://other.com/logs/user123.txt" />
</pre>
```

As to the Ajax part, just do something like

```
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

See also my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet) for more extensive examples.

Comment: Thanks, examples help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

JSP:

```
<% BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log.txt")); %>
<% String line; %>
<% while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { %>
   <%=line %>
<% } %>
```

This will work because jsp's can do anything Java can do. However, for larger projects you should look into using a Model-View-Controller implementation. There are several frameworks that can assist with this, such as Spring or Struts.

Comment: ...or if the content of log is the only thing displayed in the page, you can do the code above in your servlet without forwarding to JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did like:

```
res.setContentType("text/plain");
            request.setAttribute(REQUEST_IS_LOG, logs);     
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, res);
            return;
```

Before I write like:

```
java.io.OutputStream result=res.getOutputStream();
```

that was why I couldn't use the method, which I wrote above.
I just change to file like:

```
java.io.OutputStream result = new java.io.FileOutputStream((destinationDir+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"result"+n+"."+targetFormat.toLowerCase()));
```

and it works!