# How to read from a text file into an html page using Java Servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I am trying to create an HTML form which displays text from a text file, using a Java Servlet. I keep getting the following error: Error instantiating servlet class servlets.ReportServlet.

Here is the HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form name = "managementReports" method = "get" action = 
"ReportServlet">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my servlet:

```
package servlets;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/ReportServlet" })
public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet   
{
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws 
ServletException, IOException  
{
res.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();

String name = req.getParameter("filename");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader("c:/Consignment.txt"));

String str;
while( (str = br.readLine()) != null )
{
 pw.println(str + "<BR>");
}

br.close();
pw.close();
}
}
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CustomerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.CustomerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ConsignmentServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.ConsignmentServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ReportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.ReportServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: paste you web.xml

Comment: try debugging it - very similar to your last question

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593832/how-do-i-read-text-file-and-output-in-servlet

Comment: I have added my web.xml

Comment: Does anybody have any suggestions? I am still struggling with this

Answer (score -1):

Try this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868004/how-to-read-a-text-file-from-server-and-display-the-text-in-index-jsp)  and try this [one](https://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/600994-how-display-data-text-file-onto-webpage-using-servlets) also. And for your error, check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883080/http-status-500-error-instantiating-servlet-class).